# Change specific values in a Pandas DataFrame (where there are mixed types)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to increase any value greater than zero by some increment (say, .001), but only in a subset of columns.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc'], 'b': [2,np.nan, 0, 6], 'c': [1, 0, 2, 0]})

     a    b  c
0  abc  2.0  1
1  abc  NaN  0
2  abc  0.0  2
3  abc  6.0  0
```

So I tried this:

```
df[df.loc[:,['b', 'c']]>0]+=1

TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value
```

However, because the first column is has an object dtype, I cannot do this as you can see by the error. The desired output would be:

```
     a    b      c
0  abc  2.001  1.001
1  abc  NaN    0
2  abc  0.0    2.001
3  abc  6.001  0
```

Is there some way to do this kind of thing without explicitly looping through each column separately?

I believe I am just missing a simple approach but cannot seem to find an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc'], 
                   'b': [2,np.nan, 0, 6], 
                   'c': [1, 0, 2, 0]})

inc = 0.01
df.loc[:, df.dtypes.ne('object')] += inc
df.replace({inc:0}, inplace=True)        

print(df)
```

Or as proposed by Tai with np.where (this should be quicker):

```
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.ne('object')]
df[cols] += np.where(df[cols] >0, 0.01, 0)
```

Returns:

```
     a     b     c
0  abc  2.01  1.01
1  abc   NaN  0.00
2  abc  0.00  2.01
3  abc  6.01  0.00
```

Comment: Nice. Note you can also use `df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, this also increments the zeros. How would you only consider the values > 0?

Comment: @jpp thank you for mention `select_dtypes`, borrowed  :-)

Comment: @campo hmm you are right. I oversaw that. I did a small fix but let me (or someone else) come up with something better.

Comment: @AntonvBR Also fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: @campo Yes, well a hax. It is however faster than the `df.add()` Wen proposed on df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

Comment: This is elegant :P

Comment: @Tai Yes, well that's the most generic and readable I think. I was trying to apply it with .loc.

Comment: For this one , notice if the boundary is not 0, then using replace will create some trouble(for example limit 0.01, and adding value 0.01)@campo

Answer (score 3):

You can using `add` with `select_dtypes`

```
df.add((df.select_dtypes(exclude=object)>0).astype(int)*0.0001).combine_first(df)
Out[18]: 
     a       b       c
0  abc  2.0001  1.0001
1  abc     NaN  0.0000
2  abc  0.0000  2.0001
3  abc  6.0001  0.0000
```

Comment: Thanks but now the "a" column is all NaNs.

Comment: @campo adding `combine_first` :-)

Comment: Very clever! Thank you very Much Wen. It seems you do not need to cast as integer either: 
 `df.add((df.select_dtypes(exclude=object)>0)*.001).combine_first(df)`

Comment: @campo yep , We do not need that step:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also only add on columns `b` and `c`.

```
df[["b", "c"]] += np.where(df[["b", "c"]] > 0, 0.01, 0)
```

We use `np.where` to fill in 0 as to bypass `np.nan` in the data.

Anton vBR has an elegant way to select columns one need.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for.